# hide the option of select box based on another select box selection JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I have set different select boxes for example

```
"course 1" (with dates - May 01, June 01), 
"course 2 (with dates - June 01, August 01)" 
"course 3 (with dates - July 01, June 01)".
```

So the requirement is If user select `"Course 1" and select "date - June 1"` and then if user selects `"Course 2" or "course 3"` then i have to put the logic where user cannot select date as `"June 1 for course 2"` and `"course 3"` because user has already selected the `"June 1"` for `"Course 1"`. so user can only select `"August 01"` for the `"Course 2"` and `"July 01"` for `"Course 3"`.

Please see the html code

```
<select class="c1"><option value="May 01">May 01</option><option value="June 01">June 01</option></select>
<select class="c2"><option value="June 01">June 01</option><option value="Aug 01">Aug 01</option></select>
<select class="c3"><option value="June 01">June 01</option><option value="July 01">July 01</option></select>
```

So is there any way to achieve that using JQuery?

Comment: Completely possible, but you will need to provide your `HTML` as it depends on how it is coded.

Comment: I have put the html code in my original question

Comment: It would help if you could make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) :)

Comment: Also, I'm assuming when the user clicks on, say June 01 in the first `select`, you want the other June 01's to disappear then REappear if May 01 is clicked in the first `select`. Correct?

Comment: @waffle, Yes it is correct.

Comment: I have created a jsfiddle page. Please check http://jsfiddle.net/8uvB8/. I will really appreciate your help

Comment: @WaffleWhomper, I have created a jsfiddle link. Can you please check and help me to sort it out? http://jsfiddle.net/8uvB8/